# Using distinct with stuff/for xml path('')

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'd like to put together only unique values in the concatenated string.  My code is currently:

```
select rc.Routage
    , COUNT(distinct rc.Event)
    , STUFF((select ', ' + cast(rcA.Event as varchar)
            from Receiving rcA
            where rcA.supplier = 'user'
            for xml path(''))
        , 1, 1, '')
from Receiving rc
where rc.supplier = 'user'
group by rc.Routage
order by COUNT(distinct rc.Event)desc
```

This gives me the output I'd expect, but I would like to eliminate the duplicate values in the stuff/for xml path field.

I've tried various combinations of `distinct` and `group by` in the stuff/xml section, but can't piece it together properly.

To clarify, for `COUNT(distinct rc.Event)` = 2, I would like to see 2 distinct events from the stuff clause.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `select distinct` in the subquery:

```
select rc.Routage,
       count(distinct rc.Event),
       stuff((select distinct ', ' + cast(rcA.Event as varchar(max))
              from Receiving rcA
              where rcA.supplier = 'user' and
                    rcA.DATETIME > '20170322' and
                    rc.Routage = rcA.Routage
              for xml path('')
             ), 1, 2, '')
from Receiving rc
where rc.supplier = 'user' and rc.DATETIME > '20170322'
group by rc.Routage;
```

Notes:

- In SQL Server, *never* use `varchar()` (or related types) without a length.  The default varies by context and you are (potentially) introducing a bug that is really hard to find.
- You want the `stuff()` to remove two characters, not 1, because you have a comma followed by a space.
- This formulation assumes that `Event` does not have XML special characters.  It is easy to tweak if that is an issue.

Also, this type of query is usually faster if you eliminate the duplicates in a subquery:

```
select rc.Routage, rc.numEvents,
       stuff((select distinct ', ' + cast(rcA.Event as varchar(max))
              from Receiving rcA
              where rcA.supplier = 'user' and
                    rcA.DATETIME > '20170322' and
                    rc.Routage = rcA.Routage
              for xml path(''), type
             ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
                    ), 1, 2, ''
            )
from (select rc.Routage, count(distinct rc.Event) as numEvents
      from Receiving rc
      where rc.supplier = 'user' and rc.DATETIME > '20170322'
      group by rc.Routage
     ) rc;
```

Answer (score 4):

Do the `distinct` in a subquery, before the XML processing gets anywhere near it:

```
select rc.Routage
    , COUNT(distinct rc.Event)
    , STUFF((select ', ' + cast(rcA.Event as varchar)

            from (select distinct Event from Receiving a
                  where supplier = 'user'
                   and DATETIME > '20170322'
                   and rc.Routage=a.Routage
            ) rcA

            for xml path(''))
        , 1, 1, '')
from Receiving rc
where rc.supplier = 'user'
    and rc.DATETIME > '20170322'
group by rc.Routage
order by COUNT(distinct rc.Event)desc
```